# Select....into error mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure:

```
delimiter / 
drop procedure if exists registration / create procedure registration(email varchar(50), pass varchar(50), first_name varchar(30), last varchar(30), address varchar(100), city varchar(30), state_id  int, zip varchar(20), phone varchar(15), alt_phone varchar(15), outlet varchar(100), url varchar(255), bio text, out response int, out photo_location varchar(40), image_type varchar(10), out emailer varchar(20), out max_row int) 
start_:begin 
 start transaction; 
 insert into registration_application values(null, email, PASSWORD(pass), first_name, last, address, city, state_id, zip, phone, alt_phone, outlet, url, bio); 
 set emailer=email; 
 select id into max_row from registration_application where email=email order by id;  
 commit; 
 set response= 1; 
end start_;
```

The id is a primary key, which is auto_incremented, and the email field has unique index; so, it's impossible for 2 rows to contain the same email; however, anytime I call that procedure, the 'select...into' always return more than 1 row, even though only row exists with that email address. 
 I understand that I can constrict it to returning only one row by using limit 1, and 'using order by id desc'; however, my questions are these:

- Is the problem a bug in mysql? I've seen many people online with a similar problem.
- Since I have no idea what position the id I'm seeking is (since the select..into obviously returned more than one row), is there a way to ensure the correct id will always be returned? 
  Thank you.

Comment: You have `where email=email` which is almost always true. No wonder that you are selecting many (meaning ALL) rows.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from using the same name (`email`) for a table column and a procedure parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user705339 as you mentioned above the LAST_INSERT_ID() might not return the desired id under certain circumstances, for example if you try to insert a duplicate email, the insert statement returns error and the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is undefined.

Your problem is an ambiguous reference to email, `where email=email` is always true returning all rows in table `registration_application`. And not the expected single row.

What you could do, since you are setting `emailer=email`, is:

```
select id into max_row from registration_application where email=emailer order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function is the correct way to get the last auto increment value.

Comment: While you are technically correct, in this case, your answer won't work because the code won't be set always select the last id inserted; it's set to select an id based on the email parameter given. Thanks for the reply, nonetheless.

Comment: @user705339: But that's the same email you just inserted, right?

Comment: Yes, but next time, the email I need might not be the same one I just inserted. That code was just an example of how the procedures will be built; that's why obtaining the last insert id isn't always the right way for me